# `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in React in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in Reactjs, I'm working on a react project which uses an API I want the component to be functional but when I make it a functional component it gives me the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

here is my component `projects.component.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Projects() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/")
            .then((res) => {
                res.json();
            })
            .then((res) => {
                setProjects(res);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
                <h2>
                    {projects.map((project) => (
                              <div className="notes" key={project.id}>
                                  <h1>{ project.title }</h1>
                              </div>
                          ))}
                </h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

and here is my app.js:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Projects from "./components/projects.component";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Route path="/" component={Projects} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How can I fix the error of map being undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your first `.then()` chain - the function is not returning the `res.json()` result so you end up setting projects to `undefined`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/")
            .then((res) => {
                res.json();
              //^^^^^^^^^^^ problem is here - the json value is not being returned here
            })
            .then((res) => {
                 //^^^ so res is now undefined
                setProjects(res);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, []);
```

The solution is to either `return` the result:

```
.then((res) => {
    return res.json();
})
```

Or remove the wrapping curly braces `{}` to allow the implicit return behaviour of arrow functions:

```
.then((res) => res.json())
```

For more information on how syntax differences change arrow function behaviour, see the mdn [Arrow functions documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax).

Regarding braces and implicit return, see the [Function body section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body).

Comment: that worked, thanks for the answer returning the res.json is working.